# Sigv4 error when calling API Gateway 'Credential should be scoped to a valid region'

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway deployed to `us-east-1`, with a custom domain and IAM auth enabled.

The API Gateway acts as a {proxy+} gateway.

I have the following node.js AWS lambda deployed also to `us-east-1` in a different AWS account to make the request using axios.

```
import { Sha256 } from '@aws-crypto/sha256-js';
import { SignatureV4 } from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4';
import axios from 'axios';


const v4 = new SignatureV4({
      service: 'execute-api',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, //provided by default by AWS lambda
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, //provided by default by AWS lambda
        sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, //provided by default by AWS lambda
      },
      sha256: Sha256,
    });

v4.sign({
      method: 'PUT',
      hostname: 'custom.domain.com',
      path: `/v1/events/${eventId}`,
      protocol: 'https',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        host: 'custom.domain.com', // compulsory
      },
      body: {
        ...request payload
      },
    });

    return await axios({
      ...signedRequest,
      url: `https://custom.domain.com/v1/events/${eventId}`,
    });
```

The above is resulting in a response of:

```
status code: 403
data: {
    message: "Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-*'. "
}
```

Please help to address the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

AWS gives that error if the credential scope does not specify the same Region as the request.

[image]

screenshot from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html

Here's the source code for `SignatureV4.sign()`:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/4493d74b/packages/signature-v4/src/SignatureV4.ts#L166

```
  private async signRequest(
    requestToSign: HttpRequest,
    {
      signingDate = new Date(),
      signableHeaders,
      unsignableHeaders,
      signingRegion,
      signingService,
    }: RequestSigningArguments = {}
  ): Promise<HttpRequest> {
```

Perhaps you could try adding:

`signingRegion` in the sign options:

```
v4.sign({
      method: 'PUT',
      hostname: 'custom.domain.com',
      path: `/v1/events/${eventId}`,
      protocol: 'https',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        host: 'custom.domain.com', // compulsory
      },
      body: {
        ...request payload
      },
    },
    {
      signingRegion: 'us-east-1',
    }
);
```

The other thing you could try is adding the credentials at the module level:

```
AWS.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION || "us-east-1",
});
```